# React - most efficient way to share data between components

Tags: reactjs, state

I'll start by saying I'm very new to React and am just playing around with having components interact with each other... trying to get a sense for where `state` belongs and the most efficient way(s) to render changes on screen.

I have 2 sibling components, `Bro` and `Sis` that are direct children of `Dad`. `Bro` makes an HTTP request in `componentWillMount` to get initial values for its `state`. It then passes one of the pieces of data from the response (`uid`) back up to `Dad` (via a method defined in `Dad`) which is then passed down to `Sis` via `props`. `Sis` then uses this value in making **ITS** initial HTTP request (in `componentDidUpdate`) to populate **ITS**  `state`.

**Dad**

```
class Dad extends Component {
  state = {
    uid: null
  }
  updateUID = id => {
    this.setState({uid: id});
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <>
      <Bro />
      <Sis update={this.updateUID} />
   </>
  );
}
```

**Sis**

```
class Sis extends Component {
  state = {
    uid: null,
    something: null,
    another: null
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    axios.get('example.com/endpoint2.json')
      .then(res => {
        /* 
          transform as needed and put the vales from 
          res.data into this.state accordingly...
        */
      });
  }

  render () {
    return <section>Component: Sis</section>;
  }
}
```

**Bro**

```
class Bro extends Component {
  state = {
    uid: null,
    blah: null,
    blah-blah: null
  }

  componentWillUpdate() {
    axios.get('example.com/endpoint1.json')
      .then(res => {
        /* 
          ...
          transform as needed and put the vales from 
          res.data into this.state accordingly...
        */

        // pass uid back up to Dad to be passed down to Sis
        this.props.update(res.data.uid);
      });
  }

  render () {
    return <section>Component: Bro</section>;
  }
}
```

Is this `Bro` --> `Dad` --> `Sis` passing of data the right way to do this? This seems a bit slow and perhaps unnecessarily complicated to me... I think. The alternate ways i can think of doing it are:

1. have `Sis` make its initial HTTP request in `componentWillMount` and fetch the value of `uid` on its own. This would eliminate the need to pass it from one child to the parent to the other child, but it would involve a partially redundant query on the backend which is why I chose not to go this route.
2. have `Dad` make an HTTP request that performs 1 combined query to return the data needed by both `Bro` and `Sis` and pass it down to each accordingly. As it stands right now, `Dad` does not always display `Bro` and `Sis` (depending on the `route`). In those cases, it would be a useless HTTP request and thus definitely not right, but I'm thinking a bit of restructuring may make this viable... 
   perhaps nesting `Dad` in something like `Grandpa` and letting `Grandpa` take care of the routing while `Dad` fetches the data for `Bro` and `Sis`.

So I guess ultimately my question is: should I be passing data between child/adjacent/sibling components via their parent component or should the parent component be the source of the data for both children and pass it down to each accordingly?

Comment: "Correct" is subjective and opinion based. It's definitely not the best option. I see no reason why `Dad` shouldn't do both requests and just pass props to children. Or, even better, use Redux architecture. Then it won't matter which component starts the request and there will be no need to send state up because everything will be stored in a shared state.

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted. The question completely makes sense although it's opinion-based.

Comment: I edited he title to sound less opinion-based. In general, is there any advantage to having each component fetch its own data rather than having the parent fetch it for both?

Comment: @Sulthan - I haven't quite gotten to Redux yet. Bu my understanding is that it allows for a global state store accessible by any component at any time. This seems like the exact solution needed. Are there any drawbacks to using it in a scenario such as this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be calling an HTTP request in `componentWillMount()`. Instead do so in `componentDidMount()` as stated in [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)

Your method is complete fine. However based on the container/presentational (smart/dump) components strategy you'd better do all your data fetching in `<Dad />` component, then pass down the required data to the children. This way it would be so much easier to keep track of your requests and your data won't be scattered about.

An alternative is to use 3rd-party libraries such as [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [Mobx State Tree](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree). I'm not sure about Mobx, but what Redux does is it keeps the state outside of the components and make it available to the whole application by React context. You should be thinking about using this as it's extremely powerful and easy to learn

Last but no least, I will include a couple of posts here about container/presentational components pattern:

- [From Dan Abramov](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) - The creator of Redux
- [Another medium post](https://medium.com/@yassimortensen/container-vs-presentational-components-in-react-8eea956e1cea)

Comment: great articles... and Redux sounds very promising - I've got some refactoring to do.... thanks!

Comment: @Daveh0 if it helps you, an upvote and acceptance would help. Thanks! x

Comment: I already did up vote... and I just want to see if any other answers roll in before accepting. Thx again.